# How can I power my nine SG90 servos along side an Arduino?

Tags: servo

I'm working on a project right now. I need to power nine [servos](https://www.addicore.com/FS90-Mini-Servo-p/AD113.htm) and two DC motors along side an Arduino Uno R3 at the same time with a 7 volt lithium ion battery pack.  I am confused about the power supply. How should I power them all?

Comment: What are the specs of servos and motors (voltages, currents)? Anyway, you should supply these devices, independently of Arduino, with an SMPS ... with a "good wiring star" common ground.

Comment: What voltage does the motors/drivers for said motors take?

Comment: SG90 stall current 750 mA ... x 9 = ... + I motors ... So, use smps with current limited.

Comment: SG90 stall current at **6V** is 800mA. Whilst I would strongly recommend a separate supply for the servos, note that your battery pack at 7V exceeds their maximum supply voltage specification. It's good practice to separate delicate electronics from electromechanical components. Just common the 0V rails of the two supplies.